# Does minifying google ad code will violate any adsense policy?

Tags: html, minify, adsense

Here is an example of the default Adsense code,

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

after minifying,

the "double quotation marks" are stripped off from the code.

```
<ins class=adsbygoogle style=display:block data-ad-client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxx data-ad-slot=xxxxxxxxxx data-ad-format=auto data-full-width-responsive=true></ins><script>(adsbygoogle=window.adsbygoogle||[]).push({});</script>
```

Does, the stripping of the double quotation mark violate any Adsense policy.

If anyone has any idea regarding this, please share.

Thank You.

Comment: It's ok to minify as long as you can guarantee html is still correct, which I assume you will. For example in your example you have to guarantee that `display:block` doesn't have spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this will violate the adsense policy. As google doesn't allow the code to appear on single line.

Please refer [this](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9189018?hl=en) link for all your queries:

Comment: Single-lining code might not work on certain CMS but generally it's ok to do. The help article says not to inline code as general practice but it doesn't violate policies if developer wants to optimize html. It's still valid html after all.